# Time jumps in Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, chronology

I have always been a little bit confused about the time generally in Star wars and time jumps between each episode. According to [this](https://www.quora.com/Does-Star-Wars-Galaxy-have-time-zone), there is a time zone in Star wars and it is based on Coruscant time and its similiar to our Earth.

> According to Fandom’s Star Wars Wikia, the time measurement and
>   calendars are based off the size and movement of the lovely planet of
>   Coruscant. It is very similar to Earth, being that 60 seconds equals 1
>   minute, 60 minutes equals 1 hour, and 24 hours is a day.
>   But, with the exception that 5 days are equal to a week, 7 weeks are
>   35 days, totaling one month, and 10 months plus 3 festival weeks, plus
>   3 holidays, equals 368 days, or 1 year.
>
> So, in theory, yes! The galaxies within the Star Wars Universe could
>   have time zones based on moving planets and their respective
>   calendars.

So my question is - may anybody help me constructing complete timeline in Star Wars? I found some articles mentioning time jumps, but I was not able to constuct whole timeline.

Star wars episodes chronologically (what I have found out yet)

**Episode I – A Phantom Menace (1999)**

10 years

**Episode II – Attack of the Clones (2002)**

3 years

**Episode III – Revenge of the Sith (2005)**

???

**Solo – A Star Wars Story (2018)**

???

**Rogue One – A Star Wars Story (2016)**

??? 19 years after Episode III

**Episode IV – A New Hope (1977)**

???

**Episode V – The Empire Strikes Back (1980)**

1 year

**Episode VI – The Return of the Jedi (1983)**

30 years

**Episode VII – The Force Awakens (2015)**

No time jump

**Episode VIII – The Last Jedi (2017)**

???

**Episode VIX (2019)**

???

Comment: I saw this exact term mention in a news article about the upcoming Star Wars movie recently, and it really *bugs* me that the expression "time jump" is being used to denote something *not* involving actual time travel!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are no exact dates given for many of these, but there are "good" estimates as to how many years are between works. Wookieepedia has a complete [canon history](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media), but this also includes comic and book events as well.

- There are 10 years between *The Phantom Menace* & *Attack of the Clones*.
- There are 3 years between *Attack of the Clones* & *Revenge of the Sith*
- There are 19 years between *Revenge of the Sith* & *A New Hope*, which means *Solo, Rebels, and Rogue One* fall in between them with [Solo](https://www.polygon.com/2018/2/27/17058828/star-wars-han-solo-movie-timeline-new-hope-del-rey) taking place 5-7 years after RotS and [Rebels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels) taking place 14 years after RotS. Rogue One takes place directly before ANH.
- There are 2-3 years between *A New Hope* & *The Empire Strikes Back*
- There is maybe 1-2 years between *The Empire Strikes Back* & *Return of the Jedi* (Sources say the Original Trilogy takes place no more than 4 years total)
- There are 30 years [between](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens) *Return of the Jedi* & *The Force Awakens*
- *The Last Jedi* continues directly after *The Force Awakens*. No time jump.
- John Boyega seems to have just [confirmed](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/12/star-wars-episode-9-john-boyega-time-jump) that Episode IX will take place 1 year after *The Last Jedi*

Answer (score -1):

Between Episode III and IV: Enough time for Luke and Leia to grow up. (About 20 years).

Between Episodes IV, V, VI: I think it's less than, or close to a year. In case of V and VI, enough time to partially rebuild the Death Star.

Between Episode VI and VII: Enough time for Han and Leia to show signs of old age, and have an adult child. (About 20-30 years.)

Between Episode VII and VIII: Less than a year probably.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm able to deduce these informations as well - I was asking for some exact informations from some trustful resources. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: It would enhance your answer if you could explain *why* you believe each time jump is what you say it is. I.e. Why is it approx 1 year between IV, V and VI? Was there some dialogue of evidence in the novelisation?